# Cordova/Phonegap Crosswalk project, android-x86-debug vs android-armv7-debug

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I decided to implement crosswalk into my cordova application, after installing the plugin 3 files were generated:

1. android-debug.apk - File I used to install, had this file before crosswalk plugin added
2. android-x86-debug.apk - Generated after crosswalk plugin was added
3. android-armv7-debug.apk - Generated after crosswalk plugin was added

The first file from the list above was at the original size(as it was before) so I assumed I should use `x86` or `armv7`, well as I know `x86` is a common architecture I started by using this version, after installed the application and open it up, I got a `Crosswalk runtime library is not found` popup that ask me to installed an extra application to be able to use Crosswalk, as I don't want my users to get this prompt with this extra application requirement I decided to use the `armv7` version, surprisingly I didn't get the prompt and crosswalk was used by my application(btw the `armv7` version is 3MB smaller than the `x86` version).

**Details:**

- I installed it on Android 4.4.4
- Cordova version 5.4.1
- Crosswalk version 1.4.0

**My question:**

Why this prompt is showing on `x86` and not at `armv7` and why it's architecture  related(if it is)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using Crosswalk in "shared" mode, this is why you are getting that popup asking you to install Crosswalk runtime. In short, the Crosswalk runtime is not embedded with your app. It should not be architecture related. I would say that the problem is in configuration.

By the way, what do you use for making your application use Crosswalk WebView?

Comment: I used this link: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html I still can't understand why the configuration is the problem, I will retest.

Comment: So you use "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview". I use this plugin too and don't have such issues with it. Can you paste the preferences from config.xml file which was added by this plugin after building the app? I would also recommend you to try to remove android platform, add it again and build the app.

Comment: I will retest it later, but for now, basically you say that both `x86` and `armv7` shouldn't show that popup and it's probably something with the way I installed it(installed the "shared" version)?

Comment: Yes. You can start with checking "xwalkMode" preference in your config.xml file. This preference value should be set to "embedded". If you can't find this preference or it's value set to "shared" - then that's the issue you should be dealing with.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I understand now, have a nice day